# 2D Radom Walk with Mpi

Tags: mpi, deadlock, random-walk

I'm trying to extend the code found [here](https://github.com/wesleykendall/mpitutorial/tree/gh-pages/tutorials/point-to-point-communication-application-random-walk/code) for the random walk problem to handle walkers walking in a 2D grid in 4 directions. To simplify the problem a bit, my code assumes the subdomain size to be always 4 and the number of processes (world size) is always a perfect square that will be used to calculate the grid. My first step is calculating the 4 neighbors of each process. Then I do the walk all that seems to be fine. my problem is the program seems to always reach a deadlock and I'm unable to find an efficient way to solve it. My idea was to calculate the row index of each process in the grid and processes in the even rows send first i.e.

```
       -----
Row 0  |0|1|     <--- Processes in the even grid row send first
Row 1  |2|3|     <--- Processes in the odd grid row receive first 
       -----
```

However, that doesn't seem to work, here's my code for the send/receive

```
   if ( process_row % 2 == 0)  //Processes on the even grid index will send first, that should make the program deadlock free
{
     cout << "Process " << world_rank << " sending " << outgoing_up_walkers.size()
         << " outgoing up walkers to process " <<neigbours[0]
         << endl;
  // Send all outgoing walkers to the next process.
  send_outgoing_walkers(&outgoing_up_walkers, world_rank,
      world_size, neigbours[0]);

  cout << "Process " << world_rank << " waiting to recieve incoming up walkers" << endl;
  receive_incoming_walkers(&incoming_up_walkers, world_rank,
                           world_size, neigbours[0]);

  cout << "Process " << world_rank << " sending " << outgoing_down_walkers.size()
         << " outgoing down walkers to process " <<neigbours[1]
         << endl;
  send_outgoing_walkers(&outgoing_down_walkers, world_rank,
      world_size, neigbours[1]);

        cout << "Process " << world_rank << " waiting to recieve incoming down walkers" << endl;
   receive_incoming_walkers(&incoming_down_walkers, world_rank,
                           world_size, neigbours[1]);

   cout << "Process " << world_rank << " sending " << outgoing_left_walkers.size()
         << " outgoing left walkers to process " << neigbours[2]
         << endl;
  send_outgoing_walkers(&outgoing_left_walkers, world_rank,
      world_size, neigbours[2]);

        cout << "Process " << world_rank << " waiting to recieve incoming left walkers" << endl;
  receive_incoming_walkers(&incoming_left_walkers, world_rank,
                           world_size, neigbours[2]);


  cout << "Process " << world_rank << " sending " << outgoing_right_walkers.size()
         << " outgoing right walkers to process " << neigbours[3]
         << endl;
  send_outgoing_walkers(&outgoing_right_walkers, world_rank,
      world_size, neigbours[3]);

    cout << "Process " << world_rank << " waiting to recieve incoming right walkers" << endl;
    receive_incoming_walkers(&incoming_right_walkers, world_rank,
                           world_size, neigbours[3]);

} else {
     cout << "Process " << world_rank << " waiting to recieve incoming up walkers" << endl;
  receive_incoming_walkers(&incoming_up_walkers, world_rank,
                           world_size,neigbours[0]);
    cout << "Process " << world_rank << " sending " << outgoing_up_walkers.size()
    << " outgoing up walkers to process " <<neigbours[0]
     << endl;
 send_outgoing_walkers(&outgoing_up_walkers, world_rank,
      world_size, neigbours[0]);

  cout << "Process " << world_rank << " waiting to recieve incoming down walkers" << endl;
  receive_incoming_walkers(&incoming_down_walkers, world_rank,
                           world_size, neigbours[1]);
  cout << "Process " << world_rank << " sending " << outgoing_down_walkers.size()
     << " outgoing down walkers to process " <<neigbours[1]
     << endl;
   send_outgoing_walkers(&outgoing_down_walkers, world_rank,
      world_size, neigbours[1]);

 cout << "Process " << world_rank << " waiting to recieve incoming left walkers" << endl;
  receive_incoming_walkers(&incoming_left_walkers, world_rank,
                           world_size, neigbours[2]);
     cout << "Process " << world_rank << " sending " << outgoing_left_walkers.size()
     << " outgoing left walkers to process " << neigbours[2]
     << endl;
   send_outgoing_walkers(&outgoing_left_walkers, world_rank,
      world_size, neigbours[2]);

    cout << "Process " << world_rank << " waiting to recieve incoming right walkers" << endl;
  receive_incoming_walkers(&incoming_right_walkers, world_rank,
                           world_size, neigbours[3]);

  cout << "Process " << world_rank << " sending " << outgoing_right_walkers.size()
     << " outgoing right walkers to process " << neigbours[3]
     << endl;
  send_outgoing_walkers(&outgoing_right_walkers, world_rank,
      world_size, neigbours[3]);
}
cout << "Process " << world_rank << " received " << incoming_up_walkers.size()
     << " incoming up walkers" << endl;
cout << "Process " << world_rank << " received " << incoming_down_walkers.size()
     << " incoming down walkers" << endl;
cout << "Process " << world_rank << " received " << incoming_left_walkers.size()
     << " incoming left walkers" << endl;
cout << "Process " << world_rank << " received " << incoming_right_walkers.size()
     << " incoming right walkers" << endl;
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! The first part of your logic makes sense: even rows sends their outgoing_up_walkers while odd rows receives their incoming_up_walkers. A blocking synchronious send will therefore be matched by the corresponding receive. But this logic must be adapted to walkers going right/left. Indeed, as is, all processes of row 0 will send outgoing_left_walkers. If a blocking synchronious Send is used, all these processes will remain stuck there, since corresponding receives will never be posted. On the contrary, all processes on row 1 will wait for their walkers... A long time...

Comment: Thanks, so much for help. you are totally right, I edited my code and it works now.